# How do I fill an array with unique numbers when creating a schedule for employees?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a few examples posted here but I just can't seem to be able to get my array populated as shown in the picture below.  Ideally, I would like to have an inputbox to specify the number of students and then have the VBA function fill the array as shown below:

[Link to Image](http://stephenleacock.ca/array_example.jpg)

Is this possible or am I just going to have to populate numbers manually?

Answer (score 1):

[Apologies if the following constitutes "Asking for ... clarification", but I can't help unless I hear a bit more]

I can't see, from your image, what the crux of the question is. Is your intention simply to have cell `B5` (in your example) always have a value of `1`, `C5` always a value `N-1` (where `N` is the number of students) and then follow your "rotation" pattern throughout the whole sheet?

If so, you could have the following formula in the first column (my example is for `B6`)

```
=IF(OR(B5=number_of_students,B5=""),"",B5+1)
```

Then every other cell in the table could have (my example is for `C5`):

```
=IF(B5="","",IF(B5=1,number_of_students,B5-1))
```

Or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Apparently, I didn't read your whole post. Updated to use an inputbox for how many students you want:

```
Option Explicit
Private theArray() As Long
Sub populateArray()
    Dim elements As Long
    Dim response As String
    response = InputBox("Enter the number of students", "Number of students?")
    If IsNumeric(response) Then
        elements = CLng(response)
    ElseIf response = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid input!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ReDim theArray(1 To elements, 1 To elements)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, num As Long
    For i = 1 To elements
        For j = 1 To elements
            num = i - j + 1
            If num < 1 Then num = num + elements
            populateArray(i, j) = num
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

As indicated below, you can subsitute `populateArray` with `Cells` and it will write straight to the `ActiveSheet`.

**Original Answer**
This will populate an array using the format you listed:

```
Dim yourArray(1 To 20, 1 To 20) As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, num As Long
For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 20
        num = i - j + 1
        If num < 1 Then num = num + 20

        yourArray(i, j) = num
    Next
Next
```

Incidentally, you can also populate a portion of a worksheet by using cells instead of yourArray.

If for example, if you wanted to populate the cells in the location you listed on your image, you could do it directly in the loop by using this instead:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, num As Long
For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 20
        num = i - j + 1
        If num < 1 Then num = num + 20
        Cells(i + 4, j + 1) = num
    Next
Next
```

Technically, it's faster to only write to cells once with the whole array, but in this circumstance the difference in speed is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I only resort to VBA only if I absolutely have to.

This can be done in 3 steps:

1. Name your 20 x 20 grid (eg. schedGrid).
2. Put this formula in cell `B5`

> =IF(COLUMN()=2,ROW()-ROW(schedGrid)+1,IF(A5-1=0,ROWS(schedGrid),A5-1))

1. Copy this cell and paste (formulas) it to your 20 x 20 grid.

That's it. An added bonus is you can adjust your grid to any size.